# W32.Sality Virus Cleaning/Disinfecting tool, Please HELP

Tags: anti-virus, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Is there any anti virus or tool which **cleans or disinfect** the w32.Sality virus instead of deleting/corrupting it?

I got infected by it yesterday, first i tried panda cloud, but while disinfecting .exe files, it corrupted all of them. After corrupting 10-20 exe files i removed panda and installed Kaspersky Antivirus 2011

It is doing the same, each file it disinfects get corrupted. I lost a huge number of small softwares, games etc :'(

**Please help**

I am doing the scanning after reinstalling windows, and virus is not running now, i just want to clean infected files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found Microsoft Security Essentials particularly useful when dis-infecting files. Give it a try.

Also, do not use AVG - In my experience is just removes the infected files without prompting.

Comment: you can set avg not to move files easy enough.

Comment: It is better!, restoring all files from kaspersky is another big issue :(

Comment: I was going to give you bounty, but they closed this questions. Thanks for saving my life :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to remove the drive and scan it on a computer with good AV or to boot the system with a tool like Symantec Endpoint Recovery Tool.  This does not allow the malawere to load and interfere with the AV tool. Symanetc has aditional resources here [w32.Sality tool](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2006-011714-3948-99&tabid=3)

Comment: I am doing the scanning after reinstalling windows, and virus is not running now, i just want to clean infected files

Comment: That symantec is useless in this case :(

Comment: Not sure useless since it will remove/repair malware without installing anything on the drive. Since you want to remove/repair files, it would still work.  Have used in in several cases where other tools failed.

Comment: All I want is to 'repair' infected files instead of remove.

Comment: It will repair if that is possible.  If not, why would you keep them.

Comment: PandaCloud, Kaspersky, AVG all are repairing + damaging those files.

Comment: Please explain "repairing+damaging"

Comment: These tools are removing virus from those files, means those exe files are no more harmful if i execute them, but when i execute them they are damaged. While removing virus code from executables, they are also removing important exe code from those files. Hence making them useless. For example Panda, just like a mad surgeon, disinfected a 20MB file and reduced its size to about 500kb.